# Do Primary Keys and Unique Constraints tuple in the same way?

Tags: sql, primary-key, unique-constraint

As far as I know, if you flag multiple columns as Primary Keys, their tuple will be the actual Primary Key, in that, given 2 Primary keys in a table, multiple rows my have the same entry for 1 of the Primary Keys as long as they don't have 2 matches to any other row. Am I right? And if so, do Unique Constraints work in the same way? I feel like it'd be useful to have a structure for akin to the Primary key, but its comparison to the other rows' keys are OR'd instead of AND'd, so there could be no matches instead of n - 1 potential matches, given n Primary Keys per row.

Comment: What database are you using that allows multiple primary keys? That's not allowed in postgres. Also, it just doesn't make sense. :)

Comment: Actually, Postgres (which isn't mentioned anywhere in the question) does allow the `CREATE TABLE` statement to specify `PRIMARY KEY` next to each element of the key (as an alternative to a table-level constraint) and that's probably what has the OP confused.

Comment: @LarryLustig: Do you mean PostgreSQL allows something like this? `create table test (a int primary key, b int primary key);`

Comment: It certainly allows `create table test (a int primary key, b int);`.  Reading the docs it does *not* state that the column constraint `primary key` format *cannot* be used with more than one primary key column but neither does it include an example of creating a compound primary key using this syntax.  So, it's not entirely clear to me whether it's allowed or not.

Comment: @LarryLustig: *"It certainly allows create table test (a int primary key, b int);"* Well, sure, it allows that, but that's standard SQL, and that doesn't "specify PRIMARY KEY next to each element of the key", at least in the sense that the OP and you seemed to be using *each element of the key*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is functionally correct but the terminology is wrong.

There is one-and-only-one `PRIMARY KEY` for any table.  If you use the `PRIMARY KEY` modifier with more than one column that means that each column becomes an element of the key, not that there are two (or more) `PRIMARY KEY`s.

`UNIQUE` constraints work the same way as primary keys, the tuple of elements in the constraint must be unique among all rows.

I don't quite follow the rest of your question, however, and I believe it only makes sense in the context of the misunderstanding about the elements of a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` constraint being treated separately.

If you have a composite `PRIMARY KEY` and you want to make sure each individual column in the key is also unique then you would need a separate `UNIQUE` constraint on each of the columns making up the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That sounds like an extremely odd requirement that makes me think you're actually storing a bunch of different items in the same table.